# Importing a paper wallet to GUI

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, mnemonic-seed, cold-storage

I have a paper wallet that I made from moneroaddress and wanted to import it to the GUI. Can I import it by starting up the GUI and clicking, "restore wallet from 25 word mnemonic seed," and entering the seed from the paper wallet?

Answer (score 2):

You are correct, that's all you have to do. However, when you restore it in a GUI/any live method its not a cold wallet anymore. So be very extra careful that the computer you are working has an anti-virus and you are positively sure that it is clean from malwares/keyloggers.

If you want to make your paper wallet still "cold", there are other ways you can view your funds. E.g. [How can we view the balance of a cold wallet storage and keep it cold?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2396/how-can-we-view-the-balance-of-a-cold-wallet-storage-and-keep-it-cold)